# Workspace Configuration Buttons missing in Xcode 12

Tags: xcode12

In previous versions of Xcode, the workspace configuration buttons hide or show the optional navigator, debug, and utilities areas as shown in the Apple Docs [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingtheWorkspaceToolbar.html)  They are missing in Xcode 12.  Does anyone know if there is a way to make them reappear.  I know that there are keyboard shortcuts for this functionality, but I have really grown accustomed to using the buttons.

Comment: Me too.  I guess I just need to develop muscle memory for command-shift-Y.  It's a shame they killed off that very useful UI.

Comment: Yeah, no idea why they would remove them.  It was a very unobtrusive part of the UI, and I used them all the time to free up a little screen space when working on my laptop.  Not as big a deal on the big screen iMac.

Answer (score 0):

All of these options are still available on xCode 12.

1. Workspace configuration buttons are moved to their respective sides.
   Top right, top left and bottom debug area (If not visible then show from `Menu bar > View > Show Toolbar` & `Menu bar > View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area`)
2. The optional navigation and Editor configuration buttons are also there

[image]

Comment: My screen looks exactly like the screenshot that you provided, but, none of the icons you have an arrow drawn to show or hide the console or debug area.  I can’t find a “Menu bar” menu like you describe to add them.  Would you mind showing a screen shot of the menu that you describe to allow adding the icons?  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the icon to make the debug and console area disappear is at the bottom as you describe, but it is not available to click to bring them back once they are gone.

Comment: I am talking about top menu bar, please see from the screenshot at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pldzko64ehu2f01/menubar.png?dl=0

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I am aware of the menu to hide and show the debug window as well as the keyboard shortcuts.  My question was about being able to return the icons to the top right of the screen like they used to be.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4gottcnuwowth6/Screen%20Shot%202020-09-30%20at%202.20.08%20PM.png?dl=0